# Android - Java TCP connection NAT traversal

Tags: java, android, tcp, client-server, nat

I am trying to set up a client/server model with android clients and a Java server. 
The connection is over TCP.

I have all of my code working when the android device is on WIFI, however whenever I connect to a wireless network (eg 3g, 4g) the sockets refuse to connect.

I've been reading about NAT traversal but i'm not sure where to begin when implementing the necessary steps to allow the connection.

NOTE: my server has a static IP address

Comment: You need to give more information.  Is the server on the internet in the sense that anybody else on the internet can connect to it (i.e. not behind your home firewall)?  Is the address you are using outside the private ranges?  Can you connect to other servers from the android device (browsing, general tcp or ping)?   What kind of data plan do you have on your android device (does it cover non-browsing data access)?  No answers but many questions.

Comment: Yea my server is behind my router and all of the port forwarding has been taken care of. i have unlimited data and i can use data for non browsing.

Comment: A couple more things to test.  If you go to a WiFi hotspot (i.e. not on the same subnet as the server), does it work?  Same question, but does it work for a laptop at a WiFi hotspot.  Just further things to check that may lead to a solution.

Comment: Yea I can connect over WAN, and all the ports are forwarded to my server. This leads me to believe that it might be something wrong with the android software? I'm not sure

Comment: Anything is possible, it just that so many other things are more likely.  The only other thing I can suggest trying to to see if you can get your android device to connect to another server over cellular WAN.

Comment: I will try that thanks. Any ideas on what server to try to connect to?

Comment: I'd write an absolutely minimal canned HTTP request and go to a web server.  If that works, see if things work any better if you connect to your server over port 80.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is you have a network related problem. Assuming your server is behind a router, your server socket has to bind into its LAN IP (not directly binding the public internet IP). Then you need to setup port forwarding, firewall rules etc to ensure everyone on the internet can see your server (checking with online port open checker / telnet from another network is a good test)

Comment: Thanks I'll make sure that ports are open. But i'm able to connect from a different sub net via WIFI (ie over a WAN). Is it possible that it might be something wrong with the android software?

Comment: But can you check if connection can be opened from the internet into your server socket using tool such as http://www.canyouseeme.org/ or http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ ? Ensure you type in the public ip assigned by your ISP and the port your server socket listens to. Aside from firewall and port forwarding, I know some ISP blocks traffic to unknown ports

Comment: Yes I can see that my port isn't open using one of these tools, however i set up all the port forwarding on my router and made sure that the firewall on my server allows traffic on my specific port. I guess i'll just have to do some troubleshooting

Comment: Keep on grinding until you see your port open :) Dealing with network infrastructure is always a battle